# why shell script code in c++ don't work?

Tags: c++, shell, ubuntu

I need to know the next free line in the console (Ubuntu), so I wrote this code in C++

```
using namespace std;
#define SCRIPTGETNEXTLINE "#!/bin/bash \n\
echo -en \"\\E[6n\"\n\
read -sdR CURPOS
CURPOS=${CURPOS#*[}\n\
CURPOS=$(echo $CURPOS | cut -d ';' -f 1)\n\
echo $CURPOS"

int main (){
    system(SCRIPTGETNEXTLINE);
    return 0;
}
```

But I got the error:

```
sh: 2: read: Illegal option -s
```

In the script this works

```
#/bin/bash
echo -en "\E[6n"
read -sdR CURPOS
CURPOS=${CURPOS#*[}
CURPOS=$(echo $CURPOS | cut -d ';' -f 1)
echo $CURPOS
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Because a shell script and C++ code are two entirely different things

Comment: If that script is in the file named `myscript`, what do you get when you run `sh myscript`?

Comment: @zzxyz: A shell script and a C++ program invoking a shell script aren't that different. (Though this is definitely not the best way to go about it)

Comment: There is no `read` command in your first example. The hashbang in your second example is just a hash; that is, it is not your real example. What else here is different to the reality...? Present your [MCVE] without modification, so that we don't have to waste time guessing what you're _actually_ running.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Oh..yeah...fair enough...I missed the `\\` continuations on the first read...

Comment: @WilliamPursell the same error.

Comment: @wellar, and what does that tell you?

Comment: Sorry, I hate vague leading questions: it tells you that C++ is not particularly relevant to your problem.  The issue is simply that C++ is invoking the script exactly they same way it is invoked when you run `sh myscript`.  When you understand why that's an issue, your problem will  be solved.

Answer (score 2):

The -s option is understood by the `read` command of `bash`, but you are running it under `sh` and the `read` of a Posix shell does not know about -s. Note that the `#!` line is ignored in your case, because you are passing the whole command as a string.

I suggest that you write your script to a file *x* and then execute the file by

```
system("bash x")
```

This would then display the value of the variable CURPOS to your terminal.